# parsing PATH env and add a path to it if not there

Tags: bash, shell, path, zsh

My goal is to add ***/opt/homebrew/bin*** to PATH in the shell script.
However, I have failed so far.

What I want to do

1. check if the path already exists.
2. if not, add a path to PATH environment variable

```
#!/bin/bash

function addPath() {
      search_path="/opt/homebrew/bin"
      local IFS=:
      for path in $PATH
      do
          if [[ "${path}" == "${search_path}" ]]; then
          echo "found"
          break
      else
              echo "not found"
          fi
      done
      export PATH="/usr/homebrew/bin:${PATH}" >> ~/.zshrc                             
}
   
findPath
exit 0
```

The script fails because it adds a path even if it already exists.
To achieve the goal, how should I change the looping structure?
Hope this question is not duplicate.

Comment: You can't be asking about [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] at the same time, you must be using one or the other. Some of the answers in the duplicate will work even for `zsh` though.

Comment: @AnimalFarm : In zsh, this would be trivial to achieve. In bash it is a bit tricky. Please make up your mind which shell you are interested in.

Comment: @tripleee  I am still looking for the solution for zsh. But I solved the problem for bash by watching the past linked question.